# Custom taxonomy for attachment post type shows nothing

Tags: php, wordpress

I used the plugin called "[Toolset Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/)" to manage the custom and built-in Wordpress post types and taxonomies etc. Everything works fine except when adding a custom taxonomy for the Wordpress built-in post type: `attachment`. Unlike any other post types, when I try to view the archive page of a specific term like for example a media has an albums (test.com/album/mix-photos) the `have_posts()` function returns `false` Any help and or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out. When it comes to attachment post type, you have to add the `'post_status' => 'inherit'` to the query. So to achieve this, just add a filter on functions.php file.

```
function attachment_modify_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_tax('album') && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_status', 'inherit' );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'attachment_modify_query');
```